# Magento 2 validate the form input using plugin and save the modified data

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, plugin, around-plugin

I am using custom plugin to validate the user input for customer profile.

I have created Module Company_Module  and create di.xml file in etc to verify the input given by the user:

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost">

 <plugin name="restrictEditInfo" type="Company\Mymodule\Plugin\Controller\Customer\EditPost" />

</type>
```

For this in my **EditPost**  plugin file i have given following code:

```
public function aroundExecute(
    \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
)
{


    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $requestParameters = $subject->getRequest()->getPostValue();

    if ($this->preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/',$requestParameters['firstname']))
    {                  
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Special Characters are not allowed.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
    }
 return $proceed();  

}
```

This validates the input given by the user and prevent form saving if any special characters are given by the user.

Now issue is:  I want to send modified output. It means if customer enter any special characters in input then i want to remove those tags and save it as normal string. To do so i am doing **preg_replace** which works fine but to save the modified data  i am passing the **$requestParameter** in proceed method.

```
    return $proceed($requestParamaters);
```

To save the modified data i am passing $requestparamaters In  proceed method but it's not working.

To debug this i checked after this around method call is going into controller which is showing the same input given by the user not the modified output i given from the proceed method.

How can i pass my modified input to save?  How can i pass modified output for save?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `execute()` method of the controller has no input parameter, therefore `$proceed($requestParamaters)` can't work.
In the controller the  data is taken from the post input parameter (`$this->getRequest()->getPostValue()`) therefore you have to change that data in your plugin.

You can use the method `$subject->getRequest()setPostValue($name, $value)` for that. For example for the firstname you can use

`$subject->getRequest()->setPostValue('firstname', $requestParameters['firstname'])`

Comment: Good Explanation,  Thank you for your help. Appreciate it a lot.